# My own Validation Methods( CodeIgniter ) always returns an error even when i think it shouldn't

Tags: php, codeigniter

Could someone please take a look at my code and tell me what am doing wrong!

here is my view file ( html form )

```
<?php $attrib = array('class'=>'form-horizontal col-lg-6')?>

                  <?php
                        if( isset( $_POST['save'] ) )
                        {
                            echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');
                        }
                  ?>
                  <?=form_open('basic_info/edit_basic', $attrib )?>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon" id="label">First Name</div>
                        <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" value="<?=$fname?>">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon" id="label">Middle Name</div>
                        <input type="text" name="mname" class="form-control" value="<?=$mname?>">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group-addon" id="label">Last Name</div>
                          <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" value="<?=$lname?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group-addon"id="label">Date of birth</div>
                          <input type="text" name="dob" class="form-control" value="<?=$dob?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group-addon" id="label">Gender</div>
                          <select name="gender" class="form-control">
                              <?php if( $gender == true ){ ?>
                                <option class="form-control" value="male" selected="selected">Male</option>
                                <option class="form-control" valu="female">Female</option>
                              <?php }else{ ?>
                                <option class="form-control" valu="female" selected="selected">Female</option>
                                <option class="form-control" value="male">Male</option>
                              <?php } ?>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="">
                          <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  <?=form_close()?>
```

here is my controller ( form validation ) file-> /basic_info/edit_basic

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Basic_info extends MX_Controller {

public function index()
{
    if( $this->session->userdata('is_logged') )
    {
        $this->load->model('basic_info/edit_account');

        $data = $this->edit_account->get_account_info();

        $data->dob = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($data->dob));

        $this->load->view('basic_info', $data);

    }else{
        redirect( 'welcome' );
    }
}

public function edit_basic()
{
    $config = array(
        array(
            'field'=>'fname',
            'label'=>'First name',
            'rules'=>'alpha|min_length[2]|max_length[150]',
            'errors'=>array(
                'alpha'=>'Sorry a name can only have alphabets',
                'min_length'=>'Sorry a name can\'t be this short',
                'max_length'=>'Sorry a name can\'t be this logng'
            ),
        ),

        array(
            'field'=>'mname',
            'label'=>'Middle name',
            'rules'=>'alpha|min_length[2]|max_length[150]',
            'errors'=>array(
                'alpha'=>'Sorry a name can only have alphabets',
                'min_length'=>'Sorry a name can\'t be this short',
                'max_length'=>'Sorry a name can\'t be this logng'
            ),
        ),

        array(
            'field'=>'lname',
            'label'=>'Last name',
            'rules'=>'alpha|min_length[2]|max_length[150]',
            'errors'=>array(
                'alpha'=>'Sorry a name can only have alphabets',
                'min_length'=>'Sorry a name can\'t be this short',
                'max_length'=>'Sorry a name can\'t be this logng'
            ),
        ),

        array(
            'field'=>'dob',
            'label'=>'Date of birth',
            'rules'=>'exact_length[10]|callback_date_valid',
            'errors'=>array(
                'exact_length'=>'Sorry! invalid length for a date',
                'date_valid'=>'Sorry! invalid date format',
            ),
        ),

        array(
            'field'=>'gender',
            'label'=>'Gender',
            'rules'=>'alpha|max_length[6]|min_length[4]',
            'errors'=>array(
                'alpha'=>'Sorry! Invalid gener',
            ),
        ),
    );

    $this->form_validation->set_rules( $config );

    if( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE )
    {            
        $this->load->model('basic_info/edit_account');

        $data = $this->edit_account->get_account_info();

        $this->load->view('basic_info', $data);

    }else{

        $this->load->model('basic_info/edit_account');
        $this->edit_account->edit_basic();

        $this->load->model('basic_info/edit_account');

        $data = $this->edit_account->get_account_info();

        $this->load->view('basic_info', $data);
    }
}

public function date_valid()
{
    $date = $this->input->post( 'dob' );

    if( strpos( $date, '/') != FALSE  )
    {
       list( $day, $month, $year ) = explode("/",$date);

       if( $this->tarehe( $day, $month, $year ) )
       {
           return true;
       }else{
           return false;
       }

    }elseif( strpos( $date, '-') != FALSE ){

        list( $day, $month, $year ) = explode("-",$date);

        if( $this->tarehe( $day, $month, $year ) )
        {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    elseif( strpos( $date, '.') != FALSE )
    {

        list( $day, $month, $year ) = explode(".",$date);

        if( $this->tarehe( $day, $month, $year ) )
        {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

public function tarehe( $day, $month, $year )
{
    $first = $day[0];
    $second = $day[1];

    if( $first < 0 ){
        $day = $second;
    }

    if( $day > 0 && $day <= 31 )
    {

        $first = $month[0];
        $second = $month[1];

        if( $first < 0 ){
            $month = $second;
        }
        if( $month > 0 && $month <= 12  )
        {
            $limit_down = date('Y') - 17;
            $limit_up = date('Y') - 50;

            if( $year < $limit_down && $year > $limit_up )
            {
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
           return false; 
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

I tried so many variations of dates but it always gives the error i'm frustrated already i don't see the problem with that field ( dob ), please help!

Comment: What is your precise question? What problem are you experiencing, and what is your expected result?

Comment: the date always returns an error that the format is invalid, no matter what, i even tried to return true in the callback function but still getting the same error

Comment: Have you debugged your call back and your method tarehe independently to make sure they are doing what you expect when you pass them test values?

Comment: I tried every function individually and the only place that my code can't seem to pass without problems is the part where i call codeIgniter custom validation function that i wrote -> `callback_date_valid`

Comment: but When i call and echo that function it returns 1

Comment: What are your valid date format and ranges... I see you dont like people over 50 years of age... which could affront me somewhat :)

Comment: The application will most likely be used by people less than 40 years old and   more that 18 years old, am just trying to make sure i get a date of birth in format (dd.mm.yyy) or (dd/mm/yyy) or (dd-mm-yyy)

Comment: Your form code isn't the issue... Why are you running the same code in your form validation for both True and False? It sounds like you are printing the result of the boolean TRUE which is 1. Are you? I'd be looking hard at all your code not related to your form validation...

Comment: am sorry i don't think i understand

Comment: i printed the result of the function causing the error, after doing the same to all the functions related to that function hence leading to that outcome, i was trying to find the problem to which i failed to do!

Comment: What function? Can your please be more specific on what you did... I've put in an answer to prove your form code works. So your issue is elsewhere in the code you have not provided us with.

Comment: i just realized for some reasons `callback_date_valid` converts the returned `true` into `false` and prints an error i wonder why. the same function returns `true` just fine until it's called in the `$this->form_validation->run()` then it returns a `false` ANY HELP ABOUT THIS please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the code you have provided and having a play with it. I got the following...

I have made some slight modifications. Spot the differences!

**The View - test_form.php**

```
<?php $attrib = array('class' => 'form-horizontal col-lg-6') ?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');
}
?>
<?= form_open('welcome/form', $attrib); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon" id="label">Date of birth</div>
            <input type="text" name="dob" class="form-control" value="<?= isset($dob)?$dob:'' ?>">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="">
            <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<?= form_close(); ?>
```

**The Controller - welcome.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Class Welcome
 *
 *
 * @property CI_Form_validation form_validation
 * @property CI_Input           input
 */
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function test() {
        $date = '2017/12/01';
        echo $date;
        echo '<br>';
        var_dump($this->date_valid($date)); // returns false

        $date = '01/03/1970';
        echo $date;
        echo '<br>';
        var_dump($this->date_valid($date)); // returns true

        $date = '01-03-1970';
        echo $date;
        echo '<br>';
        var_dump($this->date_valid($date)); // returns true

    }

    public function form() {
        $config = array(
            array(
                'field'  => 'dob',
                'label'  => 'Date of birth',
                'rules'  => 'exact_length[10]|callback_date_valid',
                'errors' => array(
                    'exact_length' => 'Sorry! invalid length for a date',
                    'date_valid'   => 'Sorry! invalid date format',
                )
            )
        );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        if ($this->input->post('save') !== NULL) {
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
                echo "Updating the Database";
            }
        }

        $this->load->view('test_form');
    }

    public function date_valid($date) {
        if (strpos($date, '/') != FALSE) {
            list($day, $month, $year) = explode("/", $date);
            if ($this->tarehe($day, $month, $year)) {
                return TRUE;
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }

        } elseif (strpos($date, '-') != FALSE) {
            list($day, $month, $year) = explode("-", $date);
            if ($this->tarehe($day, $month, $year)) {
                return TRUE;
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        } elseif (strpos($date, '.') != FALSE) {

            list($day, $month, $year) = explode(".", $date);

            if ($this->tarehe($day, $month, $year)) {
                return TRUE;
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function tarehe($day, $month, $year) {

        $first = $day[0];
        $second = $day[1];

        if ($first < 0) {
            $day = $second;
        }

        if ($day > 0 && $day <= 31) {
            $first = $month[0];
            $second = $month[1];

            if ($first < 0) {
                $month = $second;
            }

            if ($month > 0 && $month <= 12) {
                $limit_down = date('Y') - 17;
                $limit_up = date('Y') - 50;
                if ($year < $limit_down && $year > $limit_up) {

                    return TRUE;
                } else {

                    return FALSE;
                }
            } else {

                return FALSE;
            }
        } else {

            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

So I have added your code to my welcome.php controller.

1. Created a test method to test your date formats **/welcome/test** to test your callback code and the tarehe method... to test the formats and values...
2. I have the form method to test your form for dob with the callback.
   **welcome/form**

You seriously need to look at the code in your $this->form_validation_>run() section of your controller... Why the same code for both the True and False conditions and what does that code do?

Is that your real problem?

Comment: All of this is totally right thank you, but my problem start and end in that `$this->form_validation_>run()` because the same function `date_valid()` with the same argument returns two different results when i call it as it and when it gets called in the `$this->form_validation_>run()` to which it's cause an error

Comment: and if you dont mind me asking, what exactly do you mean when you say 'Why the same code for both the True and False conditions'

Comment: Okay MY BAD, now i get it. The thing is, that page with a form already filled with data from the database is for a user to edit their information,  when a user changes the info and submits the form they will be returned to that same page but with updated info that they just submitted that's why you see a function `$this->edit_account->get_account_info();` getting the  info from the database before loading the view... I hope you understand my reasons for doing that. But if you have a better idea to go about it, please i would love learn a better way to that. Thanks!